# Unable to send input data to function and return it as table

Tags: javascript, html, function, input

I have a form with multiple inputs.  I'm trying to specifically send text inputs to a function and have the function return the var as a table.  I am able to send the input and return a table, but the table only appears for a brief second when I click a submit button, then the page seems to refresh.  I have the submit input set to onclick="function()".

Does anybody have any ideas as to why after I click submit, the page refreshes and I loose the data in the table? I would appreciate some ideas of what the proper way is to go about this problem.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [How-to-Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `onclick="function(event){event.preventDefault(); /*your code here*/}"` to cancel the refresh

Comment: I attempted this and did not have any luck with it.  It may have been some incorrect coding on my part though.  Doing what was suggested below and changing it from a submit button to a regular button fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use a regular button instead of a submit button:

`<button onclick="function()">Function</button>`

By the way, I really hope your function isn't actually called `function()`, but that's a whole other problem...

Comment: Thanks! Changing it to a regular button fixed the issue.  And no, it is not called function(), just a quick example!